# LDAP search vs whoami

Tags: ldap, ldap-query

I want to ask what is the difference between `ldapsearch` and `ldapwhoami` because I really can't get ii: it looks that whoami is a just functionality subset.

I ask this because I'm writing a login system, so my goal is to check the credentials against the server. The software itself has configured credentials because no query right is granted to anonymus users.

I havn't a clear idea on what should I do: if a simple 'bind' request or perform a whoami query.

Answer (score 2):

The command-line tool *ldapsearch* sends an [LDAP search operation](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc4511#section-4.5) while *ldapwhoami* sends a ["Who am I?" extended operation](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc4532) to the LDAP server. Both command-line tools support to send [bind operations](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc4511#section-4.2) of various kinds before that.

If you implement a login system you normally bind as a service account to the LDAP server, search the user's entry with a filter containing the input username and then send a simple bind operation with the user entry's DN and the user's password.